# Sending signals to usb barcode scanner

Tags: delphi, barcode-scanner

Sorry if this is some kind of repost, but i cant write comment or send private message, so...
(Original: [Two way communication with Barcode reader via HID POS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3043080/two-way-communication-with-barcode-reader-via-hid-pos))

I have Symbol LS4278 Scanners and for some time now i just cant make them beep.

My "best?" try (Im trying to send an ASCII BEL char):

```
//h:THandle;
h:=CreateFile(PChar(deviceName), GENERIC_WRITE or GENERIC_READ,
    FILE_SHARE_WRITE or FILE_SHARE_READ,
    nil, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
MyPort:=THandleStream.Create(h);
FBufferOut[0]:=0; FBufferOut[1]:=7; //array[0..1] of byte
MyPort.Write(FBufferOut,2);
```

It say Access Denied, because i think kernel using the scanner in non share mode. If i use "MAXIMUM_ALLOWED" instead of "GENERIC_WRITE or GENERIC_READ" then it rises no exception, but still does nothing.
Also 123SCAN^2 from motorola don't want to update the scanners firmware ("the scanner selected does not have a valid plugin available") and even their sample software cant make it beep although it says command send success.
I guess RS232 is the key word here, but i cant find the solution how to create that kind of connection, while USB HID (keyboard mode) may still remain.
I'm clueless at this point.

Comment: What is your "deviceName"?

Comment: "It say Access Denied" - where EXACTLY ???? Suggestion: use SysInternals Process Monitor to check and log the file i/o in Windows API level and see what exactly were the parameters and what exactly were the errors

Comment: `I guess RS232 is the key word here` - and there are a lot of libraries, but they would not save you from reading the documentation about serial (COMx) ports and their settings and the meaning of their settings. For example few libraries: http://synapse.ararat.cz/doku.php/download#synaser_serial_library  and http://torry.net/quicksearchd.php?String=tComPort&Title=Yes

Comment: JediVCL library had USB HID component, though I never actually tried if it is working

Comment: 1. deviceName = '\\?\HID#VID_05E0&PID_1200#8&eda0e97&0&0000#{884b96c3-56ef-11d1-bc8c-00a0c91405dd}'

2. after CreateFile if i put there this line 
if h=INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then RaiseLastOSError; 
   --> EOSError: "System Error. Code: 5. Access denied"
line from SysInternals Process Monitor:
"CreateFileMapping | C:\Windows\SysWOW64\xmllite.dll | FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS | SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: "

3. I will check these things, thankyou

Comment: 4. I installed Jedi, compiled the demo, but when running it, it didnt show any usb hid devices on its list, and im guessing it should at least show my mouse/keyboard.

In the meantime i searched for the solution in other programming languages, and i found this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337200/motorola-li4278-beep-on-bel
Maybe its not even possible to send data coz older hardware type.